# using row_number over (partition by ...) in a view runs endlessly vs run as a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been tasked to enhance a SQL view for performance improvement that has psuedo code as follows. It has row_number over (partition by... order by...), which seems to be causing this view to run indefinitely until i kill the query.
I.e. When I run `select * from view_name where Date = '2015-01-31'`, it runs forever. But it runs fine if I run the whole view as a query (e.g. remove alter view statement on top and pass the where clause at the end of the code).

I am using SQL 2005. It maybe that SQL 2005 engine generates execution plans differently for views vs normal queries because as I mentioned the entire code in the view, when executed as a query, runs fine. How can I make the view itself run faster so it can return the results? One of the tables that my view queries (table1 in this psuedo code) is very large and is partitioned by date where each month's data is one partition.

PSEUDO-CODE:

```
CREATE VIEW Sample
AS
WITH Dataset1
AS (
    SELECT table1.DATE
        ,column1
        ,column2
        ,column3
        ,column4
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.DATE = table2.DATE
    )
    ,Dataset2
AS (
    SELECT Dataset1.DATE
        ,column1
        ,column2
        ,column3
        ,column4
    FROM table3
    INNER JOIN Dataset1 ON table3.column1 = Dataset1.column1
    )
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column1 ASC
        ) AS RowNumber
    ,*
FROM Dataset2
GO
```

Comment: what is the where clause you use/reference in the question?  Could make a big difference in what can be done or not

Comment: ha, never mind, I see it further up in the question: where Date = '2015-01-31'

Answer (score 2):

My first steps towards improving this query would be:

1. Reducing the code complexity: why are you using two CTEs? It appears from the example code that this could be rewritten as a single query joining table 1 to 2, then 2 to 3, with the `ROW_NUMBER()` directly in the `SELECT` clause. This may not affect the performance directly, but it is much easier to analyse a simple query than a complex one.
2. Reconsidering the intended behaviour of the `ROW_NUMBER()`: you are partitioning and ordering by the same column. This means that for each distinct value in `column1`, SQL Server will attempt to order the rows based on the values in `column1`; the values are all the same within that partition so the ordering is essentially "random" and any processing time devoted to this is wasted. (Depending hugely on other factors e.g. any clustered indexes on these tables.)
3. Retrieving the execution plan for this query and examining it for further ideas. The execution plan may include tips for indexes that can be applied - which you should consider, but don't take SQL Server's word as gospel.

I might have further suggestions if I could see an execution plan, have a bit more insight into the structures of these tables (including indexes and cardinality of the relationships), and know how big "very large" means to you :)

Comment: Hello philosophicles. I tried consolidating the CTE's but that did not improve the performance and also changed the record count which was not the desired outcome. The actual execution plan shows most resources consumed at the clustered index seek for table 1 but I noticed that if I replaced the whole ROW_NUMBER() OVER Partition By .... with a simple select * then the view works and returns data under 1 minute whereas it runs endlessly otherwise. Strange.

Comment: I'm not surprised that removing the Row_number speeds things up; see my point 2 above.

Comment: How did you consolidate the ctes? To me it looks like tables 1, 2 and 3 can all be inner joined directly to achieve the same rowset you have here. If not, do you know why not? That might indicate why the rownumber is struggling